# type-conversion in one function in C

Tags: c, function, struct, type-conversion, typedef

I have one doubt, could it be possible to create one

```
typedef struct whatever
```

and then if one function requires:

```
void function(char * something);
```

when you call the function in main program write:

```
function((char *) whatever);
```

is that correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "correct".  Will it compile?  Probably, depending on the compiler.  Will it work?  Hard to say, since you give no indication of what it would mean for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no defined behavior for casting a structure to any pointer type.  Very likely your compiler would reject such a cast, but if it accepted it then the resulting behavior is unlikely to be useful.

Moreover, you cannot pass a *type* (i.e. `whatever`) as a function argument.

You could conceivably pass a pointer to an object of your type:

```
int main() {
    whatever my_whatever = { 0 };
    function((char *) &my_whatever);
}
```

That will work, for some definition of "work".  Whether it is sensible depends on the implementation of `function()`.